# Blog post page height is not 100% in wordpress theme customizer setting

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

Problematic code:

```
<iframe title=”Site Preview” name=”customize-preview-1″ onmousewheel=”” sandbox=”allow-forms allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts” src=”https://arablelife.com/6-things-you-should-carry-always/?customize_changeset_uuid=3728c9be-cac6-4043-b9e3-d44c03fa4539&customize_theme=Divi&customize_messenger_channel=preview-1″ style=”height: auto !important;”></iframe>
```

Site Preview works as expected when following code removed from above.

```
“style=height: auto !important;”
```

I could solve it from inspect element but can't save file from Theme Editor.

Before asking here are some things I have tried to fix this issue.

1. Cleared browser and cloudflare cache.
2. Did inspect element and checked what is the problem. This problem isn't on all pages. Persists only with blog posts.
3. Tried to search for the file in Theme Editor (Code) but couldn’t find.

Comment: Do you have some code that we can look at to help you out?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Please recheck the recently edited question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you able to link us to the website rather than some code without much context? Are you able to target that element and set the height using javascript?

Comment: I would like to send the screenshot. But how to send it?

Comment: Add it in as a link. Upload to somewhere like imgur etc.